# Text Adventure - Inventory Drop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a rogue-like game and was wondering if there was a way to allow a player to drop an item by entering: `Drop [Item Name]`

`Drop` being the command and the item name being one located in your inventory, e.g. if I had a rock that I wanted to get rid of I would input: `Drop Rock`.

```
CO = "Rock"

Inventory = {"Slot 1" : "Empty","Slot 2" : "Empty","Slot 3" : "Empty","Slot 4" : "Empty","Slot 5" : "Empty"}

def DROP():

    Slot_Number = int(input("\nInventory Slot to drop: "))
    Slot_Number = str(Slot_Number)
    Slot_Number = ("Slot " + Slot_Number)
    CO = Inventory[Slot_Number]
    Inventory[Slot_Number] = "Empty"
```

Comment: Take a look at using [ArgParse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) so that you can parse arguments passed via the command line. Once you have tried something, edit your question with what worked/didn't work and you'll be able to get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using numbered slots (rather than e.g. "bag", "pocket") a simpler approach would be to use a list for your inventory. You can index into a list, and find items in a list by value, easily.

I would also suggest you use `None` or at least an empty string `""` to represent the empty slot ( as these both equate to `False`:

```
Inventory = ["","","","","","",""]
```

You can then adapt your function as follows:

```
def DROP():
    Slot_Number = int(input("\nInventory Slot to drop: "))
    Inventory[Slot_Number] = ""
```

Note that because Python indexing is zero-based, if you want to allow the user to enter `1` for the first slot, rather than `0`, you will need to subtract one from the provided value.

```
def DROP():
    Slot_Number = int(input("\nInventory Slot to drop: "))
    Inventory[Slot_Number-1] = ""
```

To print the inventory in a nice list you could use something like the following. The `i or "Empty"` cosntruction might be new to you:

```
for n, i in enumerate(Inventory):
    print("%d - %s" % (n+1, i or "Empty"))
```

In `i or "Empty"` we make use of the *falsey* value of an empty string together with `or` shortcutting. If `i` is `True` the value in `i` will be shown, if it is `False` (e.g. empty string) the value after the `or` will be printed instead. An equivalent without this would be:

```
for n, i in enumerate(Inventory):
    if i:
        print("%d - %s" % (n+1, i))    
    else:
        print("%d - Empty" % (n+1))
```

Finally, an example of a `drop_by_name` function, where you use `.index()` to find the location of something in your list `Inventory` and remove it:

```
def drop_by_name():
    item_name = input('\nEnter the name of the item to drop: ')
    if item_name in Inventory:
        Slot_Number = Inventory.index(item_name)
        Inventory[Slot_Number] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html), which makes command handling much easier

you can create functions for each command, that are then being called

Answer (score 0):

I took it one step further than @mfitzp and made it all one line of code so that *Drop Stick* will drop a stick. Here is the code I used:

```
def DROP(CHOICE):

    global NV

    NV = CHOICE[5:]
    str(NV)

CHOICE = input("\nWhat do you want to do (type Help for list of commands): ")

if CHOICE.startswith("Drop ") or CHOICE.startswith("drop ") or CHOICE.startswith("DROP "):
    DROP(CHOICE)
    if NV in I:
            SN = I.index(NV)
            I[SN] = ""
    CO = NV
```